# dsp.AudioFileReader function usage in Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, mp3

How can I read full mp3 file using dsp.AudioFileReader?

I can read it by chunks,but I need to read full file at once.

```
hfr = dsp.AudioFileReader('tailtoddle_lo.mp3');
hplay = dsp.AudioPlayer('SampleRate',hfr.SampleRate);
 while ~isDone(hfr)
         audio = step(hfr);
         step(hplay, audio);
 end
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use `audioread`?

Comment: @nkjt seems there is no audioread in Matlab R2012a

Comment: You need to loop to get all the data. You could use dsp.SignalLogger to easily accumulate all the data in the loop.